# I don't understand this common java principle

Tags: java, class, variables

Currently I'm following java course and I am struggling with a part of the code which I see used a lot in methods. So here goes:

Answer answer = new Answer("something");

I have a class named Answer and I think the first Answer is in reference to that. the lower cased answer is the variable. It's after the = sign I'm struggling to comprehend. any help please?

Comment: Instead of directly posting a question please google it first.

Comment: that is the constructor, please pick a java book and go to the class inheritance....

Comment: Recommended reading: [Oracle's Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html). Thoroughly, please.

Comment: Simple definition of `new` is create new object and `Answer("something")` is a constructor that you implemented in `Answer` class which take one argument.

Comment: I tried, but I don't know how it's called what I'm looking for.

Comment: The google keywords I'd choose are probably "java new".

Comment: You claim you're taking a course and now you also claim it doesn't cover an explanation on how to initialize an object?

Comment: You need to read a Java book while studying taking course. But first you need to get familiar with those first you need to learn how to google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider Apollo's comment and google it.

This is not only a java principle but a generall programming principle.

You're creating a new `Answer` Object.

Let's look at this example:

```
public class Answer{ // The class

  private String answer; // internal variable only visible for the class

  public Answer(String answer){ // This is a constructor
    this.answer = answer; // Here we assign the String we gave this object to an internal variable
  }

  public void setAnswer(String answer){ // Setter
    this.answer = answer;
  }

  public String getAnswer(){ // Getter
    return answer;
  }
}
```

So now you have a class/Object named `Answer`.
When you now want to use it you need to **create** a **new** Object.
This is done over the **constructor** of a class. ( Constructor = basically a definition of what you need to create the Object )

First you declare what Object you want your variable to be, then you give the variable a name you can use it under.

That looks like this:

`Answer variableName`

But this will **not** create a new object. 
To create it we need to give the keyword `new` in combination of a Constructor of the object we want to create.

As we defined a constructor that needs a String to create this object we need to call it like this:

`new Answer("the string");`

If we combine those two we finally have our usable new variable of a new create `Answer`

`Answer yourVariable = new Answer("the string");`

Answer (score 1):

This declares a variable `answer` of type `Answer` and initializes it with a new object instance of class `Answer` by calling the `Answer(String)` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Any declaration in Java follows the following rules:

[variable type] [variable name] = [value];

So in your case:

- variable type = object of type `Answer`
- variable name = answer
- value = `new Answer("something")`

What you're doing with `new Answer("something")` is that you're creating a new object of type `Answer` using the constructor that accepts a single `String`

Notice that the value is optional. You can just declare any value and assign a value after that

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic concept in Java.

Once we define a Java class, we can create objects of such class. To do so, we need to call a special method in the class, called constructor, with the reserved keyword `new`. Additionally, we want to store a reference to the newly created object in a variable, so that we can use it later.

To do so, we first declare a variable of the type of the class:

```
MyClass myVariable;
```

And then create an object and assign it to the variable:

```
myVariable = new MyClass();
```

In your case, the constructor receives one parameter of type String for initializing the object.